# Dovecot Unable to locate package dovecot

Tags: server, email, dovecot

Source.list file

```
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu precise main restricted universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.de/ubuntu precise-security main universe multiverse restricted

apt-get update
apt-get install dovecot
```

showing unable to locate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all precise is outdated, install or upgrade to a newer version.

There is no package exactly named "dovecot" except the source package.

```
 $ rmadison dovecot | grep precise
 dovecot | 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu1   | precise          | source
 dovecot | 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2.1 | precise-security | source
 dovecot | 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2.2 | precise-updates  | source
```

You can download the source:

```
apt source --download-only dovecot
```

or compile it:

```
sudo apt build-dep dovecot
sudo apt source --compile dovecot
```

or install one of these packages based on your requirements:

```
dovecot-antispam
dovecot-dev
dovecot-ldap
dovecot-managesieved
dovecot-pgsql
dovecot-solr
dovecot-core
dovecot-gssapi
dovecot-lmtpd
dovecot-metadata-plugin
dovecot-pop3d
dovecot-sqlite
dovecot-dbg
dovecot-imapd
dovecot-lucene
dovecot-mysql
dovecot-sieve
```